# How to convert date time stamp in query itself

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any way to convert mysql database date field to timestamp like strtotime in query itself?

my code:

```
  $this->db->where('effectdate >= ',$start_date);
  $this->db->where('effectdate <= ',$end_date);
  $query = $this->db->get();
```

$start_date and $end_date are timestamp values but database value is normal date.Is these anyway to convert date to timestamp ?
Please help.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there any way to do in query itself?

Comment: post `$start_date` format.. it it like this: **1222093324**

Comment: what you mean by `query itself` ??

Comment: @youv what about `effectdate` format?

Comment: @youv post with an example, what you want

Comment: we can write inbuilt functions query itself no?without looping all data like select function(database_field),field2 from table like that

Comment: what is the format of `effectdate ` and show example of output you need

Comment: format of efectdate 2016-05-18

Comment: then convert `$start_date` and `$end_date` in to "Y-m-d" format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->where('effectdate >= ',date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)));
$this->db->where('effectdate <= ',date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date))));
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually i need to convert the effect date, is that possible

Comment: Try this `DATE_FORMAT(effectdate , '%Y-%m-%d')`. Check this link too http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: @Abdulla you are great man you active many time i saw many questions which your answer i really inspire from u man

Answer (score 2):

1) STR_TO_DATE()     //Convert string to date(varchar => date).

2) UNIX_TIMESTAMP()  // convert date to unix timestamp (date => timestamp).

```
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(effectdate, "%Y-%m-%d")) >= ',$start_date);
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(effectdate, "%Y-%m-%d")) <= ',$end_date);
```

Note : %Y-%m-%d is the date format in string column. Please replace it with your date format

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(effectdate) >= ',$start_date);
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(effectdate) <= ',$end_date);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Instead of using `>=` & `<=`use `between`